# Google photos with Gsuite - unable to sign in

Tags: android, google-workspace, google-photos

I have enabled Google Photos in the domain admin panel but I still do seem to be able to login to Google Photos on my android device. I get the following.

When I click my account in the Hamburger bar. It prompts be to turn on backups, which I want, then attempts to login and I get prompted with:

`Unable to sign in as email@email.com`
`Contact your G Suite administrator for more information`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change might take a while to propagate - it's usually a few minutes, but it could take up to 24 hours.

If it still doesn't work, check Google Photos on the web (even through the browser on the phone), as it might show you a more detailed error message.